# Create an array out of values extracted from a stream

Tags: arrays, json, list, merge, jq

I am trying to use jq to formulate request parameters for an xhr.

The request must look like this:

```
{
  "ns:inputArticleItemList": {
    "#namespaces": {
      "ns": "http://www.unknown.com/ccp/basit/service/article/api"
    },
    "articles": [
      {
        "articleID": "000000000002158654",
        "insertCode": "62",
        "calculatePrice": true,
        "checkAvailability": true,
        "findExclusions": true
      },
      {
        "articleID": "000000000002147829",
        "insertCode": "62",
        "calculatePrice": true,
        "checkAvailability": true,
        "findExclusions": true
      },
      {
        "articleID": "000000000002103650",
        "insertCode": "62",
        "calculatePrice": true,
        "checkAvailability": true,
        "findExclusions": true
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

My JSON to work with comes like this:

```
{
  "2201299": {
    "title": "this is the product description for article 2201299",
    "prop1": "value1",
    "prop2": "value2",
    "prop3": "value3"
  }
}
{
  "2240002": {
    "title": "this is the product description for article 2240002",
    "prop1": "value1",
    "prop2": "value2",
    "prop3": "value3"
  }
}
```

So what I ideally want is the above to be transformed correctly. I see two difficulties here:

1. the article number is an "unknown" key
2. the JSON result doesn't seem to be an array itself?

best jq syntax I could come up with is:

`{ "#namespaces": { "ns": "http://www.unknown.com/ccp/basit/service/article/api" } } + (keys[]| { articleId: ., insertCode: "62", calculatePrice: true, checkAvailability: true, findExclusions: true } | { articles: . }) | { "ns:inputArticleItemList": . }`

However that fails to make a real array from the keys and insert the root/parent elements correctly.

Here is the result:

```
{
  "ns:inputArticleItemList": {
    "#namespaces": {
      "ns": "http://www.unknown.com/ccp/basit/service/article/api"
    },
    "articles": {
      "articleId": "2201299",
      "insertCode": "62",
      "calculatePrice": true,
      "checkAvailability": true,
      "findExclusions": true
    }
  }
}
{
  "ns:inputArticleItemList": {
    "#namespaces": {
      "ns": "http://www.unknown.com/ccp/basit/service/article/api"
    },
    "articles": {
      "articleId": "2240002",
      "insertCode": "62",
      "calculatePrice": true,
      "checkAvailability": true,
      "findExclusions": true
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the jqplay to fiddle with: https://jqplay.org/s/4rGV-xU05p

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`inputs`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#inputs).

With **-n**/**--null-input** option on the command line, this program produces the expected output.

```
{
  "ns:inputArticleItemList": {
    "#namespaces": {
      "ns": "http://www.unknown.com/ccp/basit/service/article/api"
    },
    "articles": [
      { 
        "articleID": (inputs | keys_unsorted[]),
        "insertCode": "62",
        "calculatePrice": true,
        "checkAvailability": true,
        "findExclusions": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ocsg-asJOc)</sup>

Comment: okay thanks again. I just found it difficult to believe that this is the only way, seeing all those flatten/add/map/reduce functions. But the way you commented it seems plausible.

Comment: Sorry but just a small related follow up question. If I have a list of objects in the input, I can use the .[] operator to make it a sequence of objects. There is no keyword in jq that reverses this behaviour, correct? (other than the one you posted)

Comment: @mebebog Not sure, can you give an example?

Comment: yes absolutely. Using this jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/QH3Rl--Wwi is it impossible to reconstruct the original JSON after applying the .data.[]? I.e. reversing the operation?

Comment: @mebebog No, there is no keyword in JQ that can reconstruct the original input from a part of it; nothing past the last pipe in `.data | .[] |` can bring back the JSON value you fed to JQ, except a variable, like `. as $in | .data | .[] | $in` will print the original input N times where N is the number of elements in `data`.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry, I will come back with a real world example that will make more sense and will be easier to pinpoint the error in my thought

Comment: ok finally found an example: https://jqplay.org/s/OyaFBTl_gc here sorting by the key name I can only come up with solutions involving to_entries and .[] and can't keep the original data structure

Comment: @mebebog So, you want to sort these objects by key names (xx.us.com, xx.watch), right?

Comment: anything you could come up with? many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the combine the inputs into an array using slurp mode (`--slurp`/`-s`) and the following program:

```
{
   "ns:inputArticleItemList": {
      "#namespaces": {
         "ns": "http://www.unknown.com/ccp/basit/service/article/api"
      },
      articles: [
         {
            "articleID": ( .[] | keys_unsorted[] ),
            "insertCode": "62",
            "calculatePrice": true,
            "checkAvailability": true,
            "findExclusions": true
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/Ip-bO3fqq6)

Using slurp mode is functionally equivalent to using `[ inputs ]` as the source of inputs with null input (`--null-input`/`-n`), presenting an alternative solution.

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/uv5ERjCqNg)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226521/discussion-on-answer-by-ikegami-create-an-array-out-of-values-extracted-from-a-s).